# Change default option for restart (if it is needed)

Tags: inno-setup

In Inno Setup based installer, is there a way to change the default selection for the restart option shown on the Finish page if restart is needed ? Please note that I am not asking about how to make the installer never ask for a reboot.

Currently, the restart option shows up with *"Yes, restart the computer now"* as the default selection and some users of the installer have raised a concern that if they are in a haste, they end up clicking on *"Finish"* button, thus causing the restart to happen.

I see a similar question [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?481397-Set-InnoSetup-not-to-restart-by-default).

Similarly, the restart message box shown on uninstalling comes up with default set to "Yes" button. Is there a way to change that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the `NoRadio` instead of the default `YesRadio`:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.NoRadio.Checked := True;
end;
```

---

You cannot change, what button is focused by default on the restart prompt in uninstaller.